# TypeError: fs.createWriteStream is not a function in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I couldn't find any resources online explaining why I'm running into this issue, even [the official Node JS docs / API reference](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) say that createWriteStream is a method in fs:

> fs.createWriteStream(path[, options])[src]#

All other stack overflow questions I found were people who were accidentally trying to access fs from the browser. **So just to clarify, I am using Node!!**

Example Code:

```js
import fs from 'fs/promises'

let ws = fs.createWriteStream("example.png")
```

Example code output:

```
file:///workspace/buz/src/error.js:3
let ws = fs.createWriteStream("example.png")
            ^

TypeError: fs.createWriteStream is not a function
    at file:///workspace/buz/src/error.js:3:13
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:198:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:385:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:88:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:61:12)
```

#### Misc:

**Node version:** *v16.15.1* 
**OS:** *Mac OS*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want use fs/promise. First, you should open file to get a FileHandle. then you can use fileHanlde.createWriteStream().

```
import fs from 'fs/promises'

let file;
try{
   file = await fs.open("example.png");
   let ws = file.createWriteStream();
} finally(){
   await file?.close();
}
```

Comment: I got an error (`Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, write ... Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance...`) unless I added a write flag to my open call: `fs.open("example.png", "w");`

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out:

`createWriteStream()` *is* a function of **fs**, but not of **fs/promises**!!

I couldn't find ANY documentation online for how to use `createWriteStream()` with fs promises, so the easiest option is just to import it from the normal callback based fs:

```js
import fs from 'fs/promises'
import {createWriteStream} from 'fs'

let ws = fs.createWriteStream("example.png")
```

I read through [the Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_writestream) on `fs` and went through all the methods in the the `fs/promises` API and none of them return a `<WriteStream>`. So as of today, it seems like there's no way to get around this issue without importing stuff from the normal `fs` API.

*Update: Changed wording to not use the word synchronous when describing the callback based fs API*

Comment: Heads up, fs is not synchronous. At least not more than fs/promise. The only difference between the two is that instead of having to provide a callback to fs, fs/promise returns a promise. Just wanted to clarify this part ;)

Comment: You're completely right, thanks for catching that.

Comment: Since writeable streams don't operate on the basis of "Put data in. Something happens. Finished." but instead let you *keep* putting data in as many times as you like, you can't wrap one in a promise so it wouldn't make sense to have that method in fs/promises

Comment: Ya, I completely agree that there's no need to wrap `createWriteStream()` in a promise since it's not something that resolves once, the current convention of importing fs/Promises *as* fs makes the user assume that all of the fs namespace is available as a subset.

Comment: Like I fully expected that if I'm importing fs/Promises as fs then fs/Promises probably contains all the methods of fs with all the relevant ones "promisified" and the rest left untouched so I can still use them

Comment: The fs/promises way to do that is to use filehandle.createWriteStream().  You await fs.open() to get a filehandle, then call createWriteStream on the filehandle.

This is *much* cleaner than using fs.createWriteStream, because you get exceptions instead of having to catch emit("error").